# Resize UITableView in interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I created `UItableViewController`. I want to resize the table and add my application background image, labels and a button... But I can't. Does anyone have any idea why?

This is what I've made in interface builder:

[image]

But when I build, I have the table view in the whole interface .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In interface builder find Attributes tab for that view and set top bar dropdown to none.

Open UItableViewController.xib in interface builder and table will appear. Open Utilities and you will see various properties for selected object. There are several tabs showing properties of said object. Switch to Attributes tab right at the top, in Simulated metrics set Top bar property to None.

Edit #2: Background image is set per view, not per application. For instance UITableView has property backgroundView which you set with UIImageView. UITableView style has to be Grouped for this to work. Buttons, labels can either be in header, section or footer views, or in navigation controller and tab/tool bar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/68fL7.png

Comment: sorry ,i'm not sur that you understanded me . I added a picture . Can you please make a picture for Top bar property . I don't find it :(

Comment: It is correctly set in the screenshot, now just select your tableViewController in interface builder, then click the tab of the attribute editor that looks like a ruler, and you'll be able to resize it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this, and thanks to the answer above, I found you have to set both "Top Bar" and "Status Bar" to None, then you can resize the UITableView.